# How to lock objects withthe same ids?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I have got the following code:

```
public void Update(Foo foo)
{
    lock(_locker) 
    {
        UpdateFirstPart(foo.First);
        UpdateSecondPart(foo.Second);
        UpdateThirdPart(foo.Third);
    }
} 

public class Foo 
{
    public int Id;

    public Some1 First;  

    public Some2 Second; 

    public Some3 Third; 
}
```

Method `Update` can be performed in two or more threads and I use `lock` to prevent cuncurency problems with `foo`. But I would like to lock only those `Foo` that have similar `Id`. For instance if one thread executes method `Update` with Foo.Id = 1 and another thread executes `Update` with Foo.Id = 2 then `lock` is not needed and if two threads execute Update with two instances `Foo` with the same `Id`, `lock` is needed. Is it possible to create a such lock?

Comment: Move `_locker` into `Foo`, then you can `lock(foo.Locker)`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this class to get a lock object for every Id:

```
public class MultiLockObjects<TKey>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Object>  _multiLocker = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Object>();

    public Object this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            Object lockObj = _multiLocker.GetOrAdd(key, tKey => new Object());
            return lockObj;
        }
    }
}
```

Then hold an instance of it in your class:

```
private MultiLockObjects<int> _idLocks = new MultiLockObjects<int>();
```

Usage is simple:

```
public void Update(Foo foo)
{
    Object idLockObject = _idLocks[foo.Id];
    lock (idLockObject)
    {
        UpdateFirstPart(foo.First);
        UpdateSecondPart(foo.Second);
        UpdateThirdPart(foo.Third);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you not be better off using `GetOrAdd` rather than a `TryGet` followed by a `TryAdd`?

Comment: @Chris: good catch, i guess there was even a race condition before. Fixed

Comment: I didn't so much catch it as comparing it to the implementation I had in my code. I also remove the lock object from the dictionary at the end of the locked code block so that the dictionary doesn't bloat too much. I'm less sure if that is globally ok to do though (it is in my specific case).

Comment: @Chris: i don't see your code, you haven't answered, have you? Putting an int and an "empty" Object into a dictionary is not much overhead. If he has millions of ID's he could clear it by himself with `_idLocks = new MultiLockObjects<int>()` when he thinks that it's needed. Since `Update` is an instance method i guess that it's lifetime is limited.

Comment: Sorry, may have been confusing. No, I have code in my solution that I used. You had answered near enough the same so I didn't bother posting my own answer, just suggested the amendment on yours. And you're right, removing lock objects after use may well have been premature optimisation on my part...

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) for storing your locks.

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, object> ThreadLockDict =
                                                    new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();
```

And use it in Update method:

```
public static void Update(Foo foo)
{
    // add a new locker object for each foo if it's not already in dictionary
    ThreadLockDict.TryAdd(foo.Id, new object());

    lock (ThreadLockDict[foo.Id])
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really different to mine ;)

Comment: Yep, the idea is almost the same ;) I haven't seen your answer before posted mine though :) It's a bit more compact.

Answer (score 2):

You can just `lock(foo)` when you're sure

- no other code is using `foo` to lock on
- reference equality (identity) is acceptable/usable, this is not using `Id`

You can not lock on `int Id`.

---

#### Part 2,

> Alas I use different instances of Foo with the same Id

Then you could try a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>` to store a different _locker per Id. But that adds some overhead, and the problem of cleaning up that Dictionary when you run it for longer periods.

Comment: Alas I use different instances of Foo with the same Ids

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is very old, but in case someone stumbles upon this and has the same issue, take a look at [AsyncKeyedLock](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncKeyedLock) which solves the problem. Note: I am the author of this library.

In case you're using asynchronous code you can use:

```
using (await _locker.LockAsync(myObject.Id))
{
   ...
}
```

or if you're using synchronous code:

```
using (_locker.Lock(myObject.Id))
{
   ...
}
```